# Looking at jobs on Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow Careers .- no dates?

Tags: bug, jobs

I was looking at an interesting job description on your website, but it carries no dates whatsoever.

When was it posted?
When do applications need to be in?

Here is the link: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/104812/c-sharp-net-developers-manor-f1-team?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=large-sidebar-tag-themed-csharp

Answer (score 3):

While the job page itself does not have any information indeed, the search results do show when each job was submitted, e.g. search for [C# .NET developers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=p&searchTerm=C%23+.NET+developers): (sorted by recent)

> [image]

As for "when do applications need to be in", I'm quite sure all jobs are available for immediate start, so the answer is most likely "as soon as you would like to apply".

Comment: I followed an advertisement from the right hand side of the page on Stack Exchange - therefore I got no indication of how long this job has been on here. Could be yesterdays. Could be last years. It would be very helpful to add a date to the job descriptions.

Comment: Agreed, let's hope it will be done soon.

Comment: @SteveStaple (not declining, just playing devil's advocate...) If the job is still posted, then the company is still hiring for it. (We encourage companies to take down their listings if they've already filled the position.) If they're still hiring, why does the posting date matter? Even if they posted it last year, maybe they're trying to hire 10 people for the same job title and it's taking them a while.

Comment: @Laura I'm not using Careers much but I've seen people complaining that they applied just to be turned down due to the position already taken.